# Rails API makes multiple database queries when similar code in Rails console only makes one database query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I wrote a simple Rails API that returns all objects between two dates.  In Rails console, the database in queried only once, but the API is causing multiple queries for the same request.

This is the controller method:

```
def historic_returns
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      start_date = Date.new(params[:start_year].to_i, params[:start_month].to_i)
      end_date = Date.new(params[:end_year].to_i, params[:end_month].to_i)
      @result = ShillerDataMonth.records_between_two_dates(start_date, end_date)
      render :json => @result
    end
  end
end
```

This is the class method in the model that the controller uses:

```
def self.records_between_two_dates(start_date, end_date)
  ShillerDataMonth.where("record_date >= ? AND record_date <= ?", start_date, end_date).order("record_date asc")
end
```

When I run the ShillerDataMonth#records_between_two_dates method in Rails console, there is only one database query, as expected:

```
>> ShillerDataMonth.records_between_two_dates(Date.new(2010, 01), Date.new(2012, 01))
  ShillerDataMonth Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE (record_date >= '2010-01-01' AND record_date <= '2012-01-01') ORDER BY record_date asc
```

However, when I visit this path on localhost /historic_returns.json?start_year=2010&start_month=1&end_year=2012&end_month=1, there are multiple queries:

```
Started GET "/historic_returns.json?start_year=2010&start_month=1&end_year=2012&end_month=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-08 20:44:34 -0400
Processing by ShillerDataMonthsController#historic_returns as JSON
  Parameters: {"start_year"=>"2010", "start_month"=>"1", "end_year"=>"2012", "end_month"=>"1"}
  ShillerDataMonth Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE (record_date >= '2010-01-01' AND record_date <= '2012-01-01') ORDER BY record_date asc
  ShillerDataMonth Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2009.12' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2009.12' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2009.12' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2009.12' LIMIT 1
  ShillerDataMonth Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2010.01' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2010.01' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2010.01' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2010.01' LIMIT 1
  ShillerDataMonth Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2010.02' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2010.02' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2010.02' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2010.02' LIMIT 1
```

...this keeps going for every month....

Why does the API have multiple requests?  How can I fix it?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I reproduced that functionality in a new app, inserted about 7 records, and I'm getting just 1 query for each case.

Comment: @Ghar - thanks for looking into this.  It seems like your sample app is giving the expected behavior.  I will keep looking into this and will post back if I find anything useful.  In the meantime, if you have any additional thoughts on how to debug this, please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experimenting in Rails console and it looks like to_json is why so many unnecessary database queries were being made.  In Rails console, the to_json command is where all the unnecessary queries would be generated:

```
@result = ShillerDataMonth.records_between_two_dates(Date.new(2012, 1), Date.new(2013, 1))
  ShillerDataMonth Load (6.5ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE (record_date >= '2012-01-01' AND record_date <= '2013-01-01') ORDER BY record_date asc
>> @result.to_json #multiple queries also happen with the as_json method
  ShillerDataMonth Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2011.12' LIMIT 1
  ShillerDataMonth Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2011.12' LIMIT 1
  ShillerDataMonth Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2011.12' LIMIT 1
  ShillerDataMonth Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2011.12' LIMIT 1
  ShillerDataMonth Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "shiller_data_months".* FROM "shiller_data_months" WHERE "shiller_data_months"."year_month" = '2012.01' LIMIT 1
....
```

I fixed this by adding a method to the model:

```
def self.json_formatting(collection)
  result = []
  collection.each do |shiller_data_month|
    result << shiller_data_month.attributes
  end
  result
end
```

I use this method in the controller

```
def historic_returns
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      start_date = Date.new(params[:start_year].to_i, params[:start_month].to_i)
      end_date = Date.new(params[:end_year].to_i, params[:end_month].to_i)
      @result = ShillerDataMonth.records_between_two_dates(start_date, end_date)
      render :json => ShillerDataMonth.json_formatting(@result)
    end
  end
end
```

In conclusion, I fixed the problem of multiple queries by writing my own method that converts a collection of objects to a collection of hashes instead of using the Rails default (not sure if Rails default is to_json or as_json).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a N+1 problem, you can read more about this here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I agree that there is an N+1 problem, but how do I fix it?  I have used includes to solve N+1 problems in the past using the Rails Guides examples, but I don't think those tactics are relevant here.  The first query fetches all the necessary data, so I don't understand why all the subsequent queries are being made.  Let me know if you have any additional thoughts.  Thanks.